# Dump video from webcam to file

Tags: raspbian, video, webcam

I am trying to capture a video with a webcam (Logitech c270) and dump it to a file. However, at 1280x960, I get about 3fps using `ffmpeg` with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -vcodec mjpeg out2.mpeg
```

**Is there a way to increase fps without simply reducing the resolution?** Did I set anything wrong in the `ffmpeg` options?

This is the `ffmpeg` output

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.2-6:0.8.2-1+rpi1+b1, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the Libav developers built on Jun 27 2012 01:07:05 with gcc 4.6.3

*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***

This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.

[video4linux2 @ 0x1399320] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Input #0, video4linux2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 8397.386391, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 1280x960, -5 kb/s, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc

File 'out2.mpeg' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y

[buffer @ 0x13992a0] w:1280 h:960 pixfmt:yuvj422p
[mpeg @ 0x139bac0] VBV buffer size not set, muxing may fail

Output #0, mpeg, to 'out2.mpeg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.0
  Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 1280x960, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0

Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=   29 fps=  3 q=24.8 size=    1704kB time=0.97 bitrate=14440.5kbits/s dup=27 drframe=   31 fps=  3 q=24.8 size=    1796kB time=1.03 bitrate=14238.2kbits/s dup=28 dr
```

Comment: You really need to use an OpenMAX encoder, which may not exist yet.

Comment: I just would like ffmpeg to dump the mjpeg to a file, no need for encoding

Comment: O, I misread - I'm tired. Yeah, you've cocked it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -vcodec copy out2.mpeg
```

`-vcodec copy` copies the video stream without transcoding of any kind.

Comment: Thank you this way I get up to 9 fps
there are however some errors like
[mpeg @ 0x1da2ae0] buffer underflow i=0 bufi=120936 size=140581